# Calculus of median and bisector

Tags: triangles

In the triangle ABC we draw the median segment AD and the bisector BE.
We know that AB=7, BC=18 ed EA=ED.
How is the length of AC?

Comment: Using Geogebra I obtained $15$, but I don't know yet how to obtain it with a proper reasing.

Comment: The bisector BE, is that a perpendicular bisector or an angle bisector?

Comment: It is the bisector of the angle B.

Comment: is something else given in the triangle?

Comment: No, that is all.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\measuredangle ABE=\measuredangle DBE$ and $AE=DE$,

we see that $BAED$ is cyclic, which says that $\Delta ABC\sim\Delta DEC$.

Let $AE=7x$.

Hence, $ED=7x$ and $EC=18x$ and since
$$\frac{ED}{AB}=\frac{DC}{AC},$$ we obtain
$$\frac{7x}{7}=\frac{9}{25x},$$ which gives $x=\frac{3}{5}$ and  $AC=25\cdot\frac{3}{5}=15$.

Done!

Comment: Thank you very much! But I do not understand the equivalence between segments that leads to the solving equation.

Comment: @G. Gadda It's just substitution of $ED=7x$, $DC=9$, $AB=7$ and $AC=25x$ to $\frac{ED}{AB}=\frac{DC}{AC}$.

Comment: my question is about the right part of the equation.

Comment: Why the ratio between DC and AC is equal to the ratio between ED and AB? Thank you.

Comment: @G. Gadda Because $\Delta ABC\sim\Delta DEC$

Comment: For this reason I thought to put in the right part of the equation the ratio between DC and BC... but I know you are right checking the result, just I do not unerstand why.. sorry, I am little confused :)

Comment: @G. Gadda $\measuredangle EDC=\measuredangle BAE$.